# in windows , how to check port is free or not by using c++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, sockets

in windows , how to check port is free or not by using c++    ( remember my OS is windows  )

.. we are working on some application which requires particular port , so help me out how to find the port was busy or not using c++ ( VS2010 )

Comment: Try to bind that port! If you failed it was busy, if not then free.

Comment: *in windows ... ( remember my OS is windows )* won't happen unless one has severe short-term memory loss since you mentioned it at the start of the sentence already :P

Answer (score 3):

The comment already mentioned the correct answer: try to bind the port!

Here's why: even if you could test if a port is free, that's just an observation at one moment in time. Another process may preempt you and take the port before you can act on your observation. If you bind the port and then check the error code, there is no such opportunity for another process to steal it from you.

Comment: What if I'm just curious (say, trying to probe another app's connections) and don't actually want the port?

Comment: @JanDvorak: Connect to it? BTW, a port can support multiple connections. Webservers may have thousands on port 80.